# Keeping my JAVA (jar) program running on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, dyno

I have made a bot in Java and it works great when I run the command:

```
heroku run nohup java -jar bot.jar
```

However, after 24h Heroku closes it because of their Dyno policy. So, I thought of making a *Procfile* in order for it to execute the command above everytime it comes alive again.

I've tried placing the following commands inside the *Procfile*:

```
worker: java -jar bot.jar
worker: nohup java -jar bot.jar
```

And I even made a run.sh file that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar bot.jar
```

In order to make a *Procfile* that has:

```
worker: sh run.sh
```

Sadly, none of this works, because everytime the Dyno executes the *Procfile* (right after I push a new version of it through git), the bot never comes alive. The logs show:

```
2017-06-07T13:17:33.651806+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `sh run.sh` by XXXX

2017-06-07T13:17:37.958327+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: State changed from starting to up

2017-06-07T13:17:37.948696+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: Awaiting client

2017-06-07T13:17:38.283581+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: Starting process with command `sh run.sh`

2017-06-07T13:17:52.807189+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes

2017-06-07T13:17:53.343009+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: Process exited with status 129

2017-06-07T13:17:53.359331+00:00 heroku[run.2087]: State changed from up to complete

2017-06-07T13:24:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user XXXX

2017-06-07T13:24:43.090567+00:00 app[api]: Deploy YYYY by user XXXX

2017-06-07T13:24:43.090567+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user XXXX

2017-06-07T13:24:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

I have no idea what to do in order for my bot to run from the *Procfile*.
Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

This will ensure that one worker process is always running.